# selenium select получить значение выбранного пункта

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
<select name="WPLANG" id="WPLANG"><option value="" data-installed="1" lang="en">English (United States)</option>
<option value="pt_PT" selected="selected" data-installed="1" lang="pt">Português</option></select>
```

не очень понимаю, как при помощи selenium получить содержимое `selected="selected"`, т.е. `Português`

пытаюсь так

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@selected='selected']")
```

но, что то не работает

Comment: Добавьте минимальный пример, с виду xpath похож на правильный

Comment: проблема в том, что оно определяет текст с другого select, я так понимаю к данному запросу необходимо дописать значение id

Comment: `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='WPLANG']/option[@selected='selected']")`?

Comment: точно, спасибо!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было в [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) указывать тег родителя:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='WPLANG']/option[@selected='selected']")
```